# How to assign values to a 3 dimensional array in opencv

Tags: c++, arrays, matlab, opencv

I want to assign value to a 3 dimensional array in opencv but don't know how to do it.

here is the code in matlab that I want to write in opencv

```
vv = zeros(800,600,2);

for j1=1:m1 
  for j2=1:m2
        w=[-k;vv(j1,j2,1);vv(j1,j2,2)];
        w=w/norm(w);
  end
end
```

and this is what I did in opencv, but did not work

```
int dim2[3] = {800,600,2};
    Mat vv(3,dim2,CV_32F,Scalar::all(0));

    for(int j1 = 0; j1 < 800; j1++)
         { for(int j2 = 0; j2 < 600; j2++)
             {

                   Mat w(3,dim2,CV_32F, Scalar(1,vv(j1,j2,1),vv(j1,j2,2)));

              }
          }
```

Comment: What do you think your MATLAB code is doing? It isn't assigning values to a 3-dimensional array, other than when you first create `vv`. After that, it's just extracting some bits from that array (into `w`), doing some calculations on it, and then throwing it away. Have you perhaps simplified the MATLAB code and removed some bits you should have left in?

Comment: there is this part of code that i did not put, because my problem is with opencv

Comment: vv=zeros(800,600,2);
for jz=1:800
    for jy=1:600
        vv(jz,jy,1)=-maxy+jy*stepy;
        vv(jz,jy,2)=-maxz+(801-jz)*stepz;
    end
end

Comment: OK, so that's the bit that actually assigns to the 3-dimensional array in MATLAB. And what does your corresponding OpenCV code look like? (This should be in the question, not just in comments.)

Comment: ... As mentioned in comments to *drorco*'s answer, I think we may be at cross-purposes about what a "3-dimensional" array means. *ner*, are you calling `w` a 3-dimensional array? I'd call it a 1-dimensional array of size 3 which happens to be usable for storing the coordinates of a point in 3 dimensions; whereas `vv` is an actual 3-dimensional array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the following syntax:

```
//initizlizes a matrix zeros, of size 800x600x2
cv::Mat vv = cv::Mat::zeros(cv::Size(600, 800), CV_32FC2);

//do some calculations on vv

//opencv version of the for loop
for (int y = 0; y < vv.rows; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < vv.cols; x++)
    {

        //access indices (y,x,1) and (y,x,2)
        cv::Vec2f wVec = vv.at<cv::Vec2f>(cv::Point(x, y));
        //calculates the norm
        cv::Point3f w(3, wVec[0], wVec[1]);
        double normW = cv::norm(w);
        //divides w by it's norm. don't forget to verify that normW is not 0
        w = w / normW;

        //do something with the calculated w vector

    }

}
```

Comment: This code, like *ner*'s sample code, doesn't actually store anything in a 3-dimensional matrix, so it's hard to see how it can answer his question. Also, surely `(3, wVec[0], wVec[1])` just evaluates to the same thing as `wVec[1]`.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan - true, I simply answered the original question, which is - how to translate the matlab code into opencv. I assume that it is just a code snippet, and that there are more operations on w later on in the loop.
I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: yes it is a snippet code, i did not put the hole matlab code cause it is too long, i am not an expert on opencv, this is why i asked for help cause i could not do the matlab code in opencv

Comment: But, *ner*, it is still totally unclear what MATLAB code you want to be able to translate into C++/OpenCV, because your question (and its title) starts off by talking about assigning to a 3-dimensional array but then the rest is about other stuff. ... OH, WAIT, do we mean different things by "3-dimensional"? Is `w` the "3-dimensional array" you're talking about? (I would say: `w` is a 1-dimensional array that could be used to represent the coordinates of a point in 3 dimensions; `vv` is a 3-dimensional array.)

Comment: *drorco*, you've still got `(3, wVec[0]. wVec[1])` on the right-hand side of that assignment, and unless I'm very confused -- which I might be -- that surely can't be what you mean. There's nothing in C++ syntax to make that mean anything other than "compute 3, throw the result away, compute `wVec[0]`, throw the result away, and use `wVec[1]`".

Comment: this is the part that i want to put on opencv, i am sorry for not beeing clear, i thought it is a " dimensionnal array since i saw 3 indexes in the vector vv

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan can i send you an email of my matlab code, i could not put it all in a comment

Comment: I don't think there's any need for that. I thought there were essential bits of your code missing because I was misunderstanding what you meant by "3-dimensional array". If it was the assignment to `w` that you had in mind, then I think you've shown us everything you needed to.

Comment: Aha, *drorco* has fixed the problem I was complaining about with "`= (3, wVec[0], wVec[1])`. The code as it now appears in the answer is OK now.

Comment: @Gareth McCaughan, yes, I just noticed that. thank you for your comment , it was a typo.